# browser.manage().logs().get('browser') logs are not retrieving browser debug logs

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm able to retrieve the browser logs using

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
   logger.info('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
});
```

referenced from https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

It's retrieving info, warning and error logs,But unable to get the browser debug logs.So is there a way to get the browser debug logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome browser logs is been set to Info, when we change the log structure to debug, then im able to capture debug logs as well. this works only in chrome

Answer (score 1):

This is the the default behavior of chromedriver. You can configure it to capture all log levels.

See https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/491.